# Operation to remove powers of 10 from a number

Tags: real-numbers

I'm looking for the name of an operation that removes all powers of 10 from a number. For example if x=25673 then {x}=2.5673, or if y=0.0354 then {y}=3.54. Is there a name for this?

Comment: Scientific notation?  Not sure it has a name.  Not sure it needs one.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of that has a specific *name* is "to write $x$ in standard form", which means to do what you want, but in addition correct what we have done by multiplying with the correct power of $10$. For instance, if we write $25673$ in standard form, we get $2.5673\cdot 10^4$.

That being said, the *formula* for your operation isn't too difficult:
$$
\{x\}=x\cdot 10^{-\lfloor \log x\rfloor}
$$
where $\lfloor{}\cdot{}\rfloor$ is the floor function, and the logarithm is base ten.